# Funções de busca do Selenium agem mais rapido que o carregamento da pagina

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, carregamento

Automatizei para que fossem inseridos email e senha, e depois clicado em "Login", até ai tuo bem, mas o botão que deveria ser clicado após o login ainda não terminou de carregar e o Selenium acusa o seguinte erro: OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException.

Estou tentando com Implicit e Explicit Wait porém não estou conseguindo "forçar" essa espera.

Detalhes: Preciso realizar essa espera sem o comando *`Thread.Sleep(MILISEGUNDOS);`*

Estou realizando a busca por *Xpath* pois o elemento não possui Id

Aqui o modelo de busca que estou usando atualmente.

```
var btnSystem = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15)).Until(drv => drv.FindElement(By.Xpath("/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/a[8]/div")));
btnSystem.Click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Tive esse problema recentemente e resolvi de algumas formas, veja se alguma te ajuda:

Utilizando um timeout ao instanciar o driver:

```
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
```

Utilizando as funções abaixo (será necessário instalar o pacote DotNetSeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers):

1. Expectativa que o elemento seja visível e habilitado para clique

   ```
    public static IWebElement WaitUntilElementClickable(IWebDriver driver, By elementLocator, int timeout = 30)
    {
        try
        {
            var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout));
            return wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(elementLocator));
        }
        catch (NoSuchElementException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Element with locator: '" + elementLocator + "' was not found in current context page.");
            throw;
        }
    }
   ```
2. Expectativa que o elemento esteja presente no DOM e visível (elemento é exibido e tem altura e largura maiores que zero)

   ```
    public static IWebElement WaitUntilElementVisible(IWebDriver driver, By elementLocator, int timeout = 30)
    {
        try
        {
            var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout));
            return wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(elementLocator));
        }
        catch (NoSuchElementException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Element with locator: '" + elementLocator + "' was not found.");
            throw;
        }
    }
   ```
3. Expectativa que o elemento esteja presente no DOM da página, sem necessariamente estar visível

   ```
    public static IWebElement WaitUntilElementExists(IWebDriver driver, By elementLocator, int timeout = 30)
    {
        try
        {
            var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout));
            return wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(elementLocator));
        }
        catch (NoSuchElementException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Element with locator: '" + elementLocator + "' was not found in current context page.");
            throw;
        }
    }
   ```

Comment: Obrigado, utilizei a segunda forma que você sugeriu e deu certo.